# How to say "unless variable.HTTP Error 400 " in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I'm trying to build a call tracking app to learn twilio and rails. Right now, I'm adding the functioanlity to buy phone numbers.

I want to do an if/else statement in my create action, where if the phone number was saved to the database, and the twilio number was actually purchased, than do this, else do that.

But, the twilio number doesn't return true or false. Here's what they say in their [docs](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#list-post) :

> HTTP POST
>
> Purchases a new phone number for your account. If a phone number is
>   found for your request, Twilio will add it to your account and bill
>   you for the first month's cost of the phone number. If Twilio cannot
>   find a phone number to match your request, you will receive an HTTP
>   400 with Twilio error code 21452.

So, what I'd like to do is to build an if statement where, if the return is HTTP 400, then do x.

Here's the code I have at present

```
  #This saves the Twilio number to the database, and buys it. 
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @phone = @user.phones.build(params[:phone])
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@user.twilio_account_sid, @user.twilio_auth_token)
    number = client.account.incoming_phone_numbers.create({:phone_number => @phone.twilio_number, :voice_url => VOICE_URL, :voice_method => "POST"})
   if @phone.save && number.true
      flash[:success] = "Phone Number Created!"
      redirect_to user_path
    else
      render new_phone_path
      flash[:error] = "It looks like there were errors with the submission"
    end
  end
```

What would I need to change && number.true with, to reference the HTTP 400 Error?

I'm not sure if this is even possible -- so if you have ideas, I'm all ears :).

Comment: before the `if @phone.save` line insert `logger.debug number.inspect`. Now try a request that would return 400. What was the output of `number.inspect` ?

Comment: Hi Timothy, I tried using logger.debug, but I'm not quite sure how to use it -- i.e how I would get the output of number.inspect. However, when I ran it in the browser, using a fake number '4544', I got -- Twilio::REST::RequestError (4544 is not available.).  Does that help? If not, do you mind sending me to some tutorials on how to use logger?

Comment: It just outputs in your log or if you are running `rails server` it outputs in your terminal window.

Comment: Gotcha -- this is what my command line looks like -- is this what should be written, or did I implement logger.inspect incorrectly? http://www.stepanp.com/debug4.jpg

Comment: your request to twillo is not working. it throws a server error. go and figure out why this happens, ie testing it in the rails console.

Comment: I phoet, I know it's not working -- because I provided it the incorrect number. What I'd like to do is to run a statement in my controller action, like if number.error? than do X. Do you have ideas as to how I would do that?

Answer (score 0):

Three years later and I just wanted to share that we have a fully featured Call Tracking tutorial in Rails to help you get up and running more quickly:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/call-tracking/ruby/rails

The application has three main features:

- It purchases phone numbers from Twilio to use in different marketing campaigns (like a billboard or a bus advertisement)
- It forwards incoming calls for those phone numbers to a salesperson
- It displays charts showing data about the phone numbers and the calls they receive

And you'll want to make sure to grab the [Ruby helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/ruby) before you get started.